# Does a USB-C hub exist with *only* two USB-C ports, one for data and another for charging?

Tags: usb-c

[image]

Mockup above.

Why does this kind of simple, compact hub not exist?

Every USB-C hub seems to be a block that contains multiple USB-A, USB-C, and audio jack ports.

Comment: The image you are using seems like an example of the exact thing you are looking for. When reverse image searching it there are loads of extremely similar products. Are we misunderstanding what you are looking for?

Comment: I made that image. It's a mockup of what I'm looking for. Splitters like this only support charging on one line and USB audio headphones on the other, not things like card readers, hard drives, etc.

Answer (score 1):

They're usually called "USB-C splitter" instead.

[Device example on Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/Splitter-ACCGUYS-Adapter-Compatible-Samsung-black/dp/B07KXRHGDS/)

Comment: Not the same thing. The port is only used for USB audio, for USB headphones.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not exactly like the picture. [This deloc splitter](https://www.delock.com/produkte/G_64114/technische_details.html) sounds like what you're looking for.